# How to set a DataTemplate with one x:Key and multiple DataType?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to define multiple DataTemplate that can be selected based on DataType, and switch in Style. How can I get this effect using only XAML code? Or impossible?

UPDATE: Sorry, my fault, I didn't write clearly. I can't set default because I want to be able to switch views.

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="xkey">
        <...... for DataType="{x:Type local:typea}" />
        <...... for DataType="{x:Type local:typeb}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="xkey2">
        <...... for DataType="{x:Type local:typea}" />
        <...... for DataType="{x:Type local:typeb}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
<ListView.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger ....>
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource xkey}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger ....>
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource xkey2}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger ...>
                <Setter Property="View" Value=... />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Style>
```

Comment: You do not need to set the DataType property of a DataTemplate when you explicitly assign it to the ItemTemplate of a ListView. Besides that, you can of course only set a single DataType of a DataTemplate, and you would not set an x:Key if you do so.

Comment: As a note, unless you set the View property of a ListView, you could as well use the simpler base class ListBox.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I didn't write clearly. I can't set default because I want to be able to switch views. So I have to be supported by the backend code?

Comment: Are you looking for [a `DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector)?

Comment: Well, I know it. Because of some non technical factors, I was just wondering if it could be done in XAML only... Emmmm, it seems unlikely.